# Poor Linux software RAID 5 performance with NCQ

Tags: hard-drive, software-raid

While salvaging a 2-disk failure in my 3-disk RAID 5 setup, I happened to notice reconstruction was faster with NCQ disabled (~90M/sec) than with the NCQ enabled (~50M/sec). Running bonnie++ to benchmark the two configurations also revealed significantly better write performance for Sequential Output Block:

- no NCQ - 85M/sec, 2021ms latency
- NCQ - 62M/sec, 57118ms latency

Isn't 57 seconds a tad excessive?

I disabled NCQ with the kernel parameter *libata.force=noncq* and ran the tests twice alternately with no other configuration changes. I also ran bonnie++ on partitions on the three component disks and found no significant differences between running with or without NCQ.

Here's the full bonnie++ output:

```
Version      1.96   ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
                    -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
raid5-noncq     24G   435  92 85154  18 53585   9  3409  93 154272  10 297.6  13
Latency               525ms    2021ms     235ms   27652us     158ms     747ms
raid5           24G   372  81 61591   7 60999   9  3130  86 160280  10 296.4  13
Latency             18784us   57118ms   11323ms   59583us     133ms     150ms
sdd-ext4-noncq  24G   513  97 73428   8 33118   4  3324  91 90266   5 170.6   1
Latency             17985us     503ms    1805ms   30066us   15626us    1341ms
sdd-ext4        24G   499  97 71223   8 33015   4  3326  95 95342   5 276.0   3
Latency             17689us    1124ms    1345ms   11202us   18187us    1213ms
sde-ext4-noncq  24G   517  97 48200   5 22385   3  3555  94 62578   3 174.3   1
Latency             22423us    1609ms    2296ms   13131us   22446us    1960ms
sde-ext4        24G   491  97 47942   5 22317   3  3281  95 62669   3 257.1   3
Latency             20081us    2860ms    2434ms   12207us   27984us     990ms
sdb-ext4-nonc-2 24G   976  99 81552   9 47557   6  3514  95 146167   8 208.6   7
Latency             13004us     227ms     758ms   40575us   59198us     219ms
sdb-ext4        24G  1014  99 79603   8 48778   6  3598  97 146225   8 310.1  10
Latency             10686us     659ms     400ms   20054us   67295us     226ms
                    ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
                    -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
files:max:min        /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
raid5-noncq      16  8997  38 +++++ +++ 18071  22 18097  75 +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Latency             25974us     695us     738us     123us      21us      43us
raid5            16  4227  21 +++++ +++ 15053  25 11634  58 +++++ +++ 20341  33
Latency             26221us     735us     735us     172us      15us      55us
sdd-ext4-noncq   16 10453  53 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ 16324  82 +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Latency               245us    1126us     895us     204us      30us     46us 
sdd-ext4         16 15339  51 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ 23763  77 +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Latency               192us     957us     641us     115us      94us     101us
sde-ext4-noncq   16 12825  41 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ 21636  68 +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Latency               452us     662us     642us     115us      20us      41us
sde-ext4         16 13185  45 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ 23033  77 +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Latency               136us     634us     655us     118us      28us      41us
sdb-ext4-noncq   16  4657  78 +++++ +++ +++++ +++  6912  97 +++++ +++ 23160  95
Latency             89592us     180us     115us     348us      46us     131us
sdb-ext4         16  5061  75 +++++ +++ +++++ +++  7011  97 +++++ +++ 23400  95
Latency             12010us     110us     119us     633us      30us     143us
```

Comment: That is quite strange, to say the least; I would have thought that RAID reconstruction would be linear and seek times wouldn't have an impact. Then again, depending on your drive rotation & interface speed the linear operations might be faster unbuffered (no NCQ) than buffered (with NCQ), assuming my understand of [NCQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) is correct. Does `bonnie++` have a linear mode? Have you tried timing `dd` with/without NCQ?

Comment: Yeah, can you post the entire bonnie++ output?  Also to make sure you are using it with big enough test sizes that it isn't buffered somewhere.

Comment: polynomial, I've added the bonnie++ output. The server has 12G RAM and it's just a regular onboard SATA controller so I guess testing with file size 24G ought to defeat the cache. Results are consistent on repeated runs.

Comment: Andrew, I think the "Sequential Output Block" test is linear. It writes a 24G file. I'm not sure I understand the meaning of "latency" in this context but I don't think it means seek time because in this test it isn't seeking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question!  It seems like the NCQ test with the RAID5 is just exposing that the NCQ is done ignorantly of how the data must be written to the disks even if it is in software (this is a really common issue with IO schedulers and hardware raid in my experience, http://blog.nexcess.net/2010/11/07/changing-your-linux-io-scheduler/).

From:
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Performance

> NCQ of the controller can interfere with the Linux kernel
>   optimizations

I think the other tests do confirm that NCQ is working when talking directly to the disk, as they either show a performance boost or are near as makes no difference to the noNCQ tests.

Regarding the 57s value it is just an artifact of how much IO buffer you have and the scehduler you are using.  If you are concerned about interactive responsiveness of the IO system you should probably investigate a different scehduler (see: http://blog.nexcess.net/2010/11/07/changing-your-linux-io-scheduler/).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just leaving NCQ disabled. It didn't seem to have a measurable difference on the other disks in the machine and after replacing the hopeless Western Digital WD15EARS that was sde, block read is now a more respectable 200M/sec (these are all purposefully slower but hence *quiet* disks).

Comment: It is also possible to disable NCQ per-disk by setting the queue_depth attribute in sysfs.

Comment: echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/queue_depth